# Creating 8x8 matrices out of a bigger matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, jpeg, dct

I currently have a 170x296 matrix and need to divide it into 8x8 matrices. Any Idea on how to do that?

```
[1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , ...  , 170]    --> 296x170 matrix 
[171 , ...                 ]
[342 , ...                 ]
[...                       ]
[49900 ...                 ]
```

and I want to convert it into:

```
 [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8                ]
 [171 , 172 , 173 , 174 , 175 , 176 , 177 , 178]
 [...                                          ]


[9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16        ]
[179, 180 , 181 , 182 , 183 , 184 , 185 , 186]
[...                                         ]
```

and so on.

(In this case, it's a 170x296 matrix, so not all of the values would fit in 8x8 matrices. The last few values that wouldn't fit can be stored in a list.)

Thanks on beforehand!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can flatten your first matrix and then use a for loop to create 8x8 matrices using reshape

Comment: You can either do as @Bazingaa suggested or simply use two for loops. The point is this shouldn't be too hard so you should make an effort yourself first.

Comment: Do you want to convert it into 8x8 blocks of adjacent values, like you would when you do image compression (I see JPEG and DCT in your tags)? Because the output you want does not do this...

Comment: Correct, my program loaded an image, converted it to chromatic and saved every pixel into a matrix. Now I want to convert the image to a jpeg picture, which needs a DCT. But to conduct DCT, you need 8x8 matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution using some test identity matrix. Using `flatten`, you convert you big single matrix into 1-d array and then simply loop over the elements in sub-groups of 64 and convert them back to 8x8 submatrices and save them into some list if you want to store them. You just need one for loop. The remaining elements that doesn't make a matrix can be stored in a list using the `%` modulus operator and index slicing `[-length%64:]`

```
a = np.eye(170, 296)
a_flat = a.flatten()
length = len(a_flat)

new_matrices = []

for i in range(0, length, 64):
    try:
        new_matrices.append(a_flat[i:i+64].reshape((8,8)))
    except:
        break
remaining = a_flat[-(length%64):]
```

Comment: Well, it works, but I have 50320 elements in my big matrix, and the program said I have 50272 elements in 'remaining_elements'

Comment: @Marius.db: let me knw what happens

Comment: will do, one sec. I can send you my full code, maybe that helps? :)

Comment: First try this. It should work. Try to see the logic behind what I am trying. Yo just want to get the remainder which will be less than 64 for the remaining elements

Comment: it's closer now, I printen len(remaining_elements) and it gave me '32'. But I have 50320 elements, and (50320-32)/64 is not a natural number.

Comment: I only get 13 matrices out of it as well.

Comment: Give me two minutes

Comment: I found it. I'm sorry I phrased my question quite poorly. Thanks for your help though! @bazingaa

Comment: @Marius.db: It was my mistake. Check the new edit. It should work

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will most likely be Scikit-Image's `view_as_blocks`:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.util

img = np.arange(296 * 170).reshape(296, 170)
# Make sure the image dimensions are a multiple of 8
img = img[:, :-2]

img_blocks = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(img, block_shape=(8, 8))
img_blocks.shape
# (37, 21, 8, 8)
```

As you can see, `img` was cut into `8x8` blocks, 37 blocks in the vertical direction, 21 blocks in the horizontal direction.

For a toy example it is quite easy to see what is happening:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.util

img = np.arange(4 * 6).reshape(4, 6)
img
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
#        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
#        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])

img_blocks = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(img, block_shape=(2, 2))
img_blocks
# array([[[[ 0,  1],
#          [ 6,  7]],
# 
#         [[ 2,  3],
#          [ 8,  9]],
# 
#         [[ 4,  5],
#          [10, 11]]],
# 
# 
#        [[[12, 13],
#          [18, 19]],
# 
#         [[14, 15],
#          [20, 21]],
# 
#         [[16, 17],
#          [22, 23]]]])
```

Comment: I see what you did, though it returned me an error : AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: You're apparently not working with NumPy. Where does your image come from?

Comment: I need to stack the matrices back together now and can't find a way to do this. Is there a command in the skimage package to do this?

Comment: Just reshape it to its original shape

Comment: Problem is, is that they have to be in the same order for it to work. Otherwise I won't be able to make sens out of my newly formed picture. I tried it with reshape but it somehow messed up the order, is that possible? @NilsWerner

Comment: If you transpose them in-between, they will be messed up. In that case, just transpose them back...

Comment: I only transposed them in 2 lines, being this one :
foto_dct[j,i] = fftpack.idct(fftpack.idct(foto_dct[j,i].T,norm = 'ortho').T,norm ='ortho')
And this one:
foto_dct[j,i] = fftpack.dct(fftpack.dct(foto_dct[j,i].T,norm = 'ortho').T,norm ='ortho')
in both of these lines I transposed them twice so they should have stayed the same?

Comment: Link to my full code ( I chose not to use other names because I don't really need anything from in the proces, only the result. I know it isn't how it's supposed to be but I've only just started programming.) https://gyazo.com/c61390db2fcc10c17d3f9a5203b5b130

Comment: This warrants another SO question. Please mark this as accepted and open a new one, thanks!